# Proving a statement about prime numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Let $p_1,p_2,p_3,\cdots$ be all the primes sorted in an increasing order.

Is $p_1p_2p_3\cdots p_i + 1$ is always prime? Why? How can I prove that?

Comment: Try proving that it is _not_ always a prime. That has a higher chance of success.

Comment: let me try. Ty @DanielFischer

Comment: $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 + 1 = 59 \cdot 509$.

Comment: That's really cool... How did you get this?!@EricTowers

Comment: +1 for actually asking this question; many people believe it without even realising...

Comment: @SonicFancy Numbers of that form occur in [Euclids proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_theorem) for the existence of infinitely many primes and are thus (by some) called "[Euclid numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclidNumber.html)". EricTowers has probably seen such numbers before and was familiar with the fact that the number he has given is [the smallest Euclid number which is not a prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime).

Comment: All you can say in general is that its smallest prime factor is $> p_i$, which is the argument to prove that the set of prime is infinite.

Comment: Prime numbers of the form $p_1p_2\cdot\cdot\cdot p_n+1$ are usually called Euclid primes or primorial primes (http://oeis.org/A014545)

Answer (score 2):

$P_n=p_1p_2\cdots p_n+1$ can't be divisible by any of $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n$, and so $P_n$ must be prime if $P_n<p_{n+1}^2.$ So in particular 3 is prime since $3<3^2$, 7 is prime since $7<5^2,$ and 31 is prime since $31<7^2$. But the argument doesn't work for larger values, and in particular it fails for $13\#+1$, $17\#+1$, $19\#+1$, etc.